# Is there a predefined class for URL in Python?

Tags: python, url, urlparse

I am looking for something like [java.net.URL](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) in python-modules, Django, Zope or wherever in Python. 
I want it preferably from the semantics **reason**, because the result of analysis of concerned program implies that the URL plays an essential role in it. The consequence is that such URL class also will have great practical usage in that program.

Of course I could write such class on my own, but I'd like to look around before I start to **reinvent the wheel**.

I did look at [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) and [urlparse](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html). The `urlparse` basically has the functionality I need, but it doesn't encapsulate it into a class like `java.net.URL`. Regarding my analysis of my program it works upside-down.

I looked also into the source code of `urlparse` at the classes `SplitResult` and `ParseResult`. They have some basic functionality and they can be used for subclassing. But I'll have to rewrite rest of the urlparse functions as the subclass methods.

I found also [mxURL - Flexible URL Datatype for Python](http://www.egenix.com/products/python/mxBase/mxURL/). It is very close to what I really want. Only it seems to be quite an overkill for my purpose.

Can anyone suggest another option? Should I proceed with reinventing the wheel?

**My solution:**

To get my URL class I did basically two things:

1. Inherit from `urlparse.ResultMixin`.
2. Define function which only calls `urlparse.urlparse()` and transforms results to
   parameters of URL instance.

Comment: Why do you need a class for that?

Comment: @Cat Plus Plus: having a class for URLs can be very convenient. So convenient in fact, that the Python standard library includes one.

Comment: @larsmans: It's not that much more than a named tuple, really.

Comment: @Cat Plus Plus: what more would you expect from a URL class? ;)

Comment: I think having a URL class is a great idea. A URL is a value object much like any other. Maybe it's more Java philosophy than Python, but, for example, constructing one from a string then getting scheme, host, path etc is a very strong case. Looks like `urlparse` does this job fine, but doesn't undermine the case for the Java class.

Comment: @larsmans I would expect setting GET arguments using a `url[key] = value` syntax.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might want consider having a look at [furl](https://github.com/gruns/furl/) because it might be an answer to your needs.

Comment: Thanks. I really like it! I'll give it a try ;-)

Comment: Downside of furl is that is doesn't (and [won't](https://github.com/gruns/furl/issues/15) ) handle [params](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10988614/what-are-the-url-parameters-element-at-position-3-in-urlparse-result). But the question is who needs `params`.

Comment: @sumid from the [GitHub url](https://github.com/gruns/furl/issues/15) the maintainer says "If their use grows, I'll happily add them (or accept a pull request)." If you need params, I'm sure you could contribute it! :)

Answer (score 28):

`urlparse` *does* encapsulate URLs into a class, called `ParseResult`, so it can be considered a factory function for these. Straight from the Python docs:

```
>>> urlparse('http://www.cwi.nl:80/%7Eguido/Python.html')
ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='www.cwi.nl:80', path='/%7Eguido/Python.html',
            params='', query='', fragment='')
```

If you desperately want a class called `URL` to encapsulate your URLs, use an alias (`URL = urlparse.ParseResult`) or create an adapter.

Comment: ParseResult is namedtuple. I can't figure out why. I want to change existing url but there's no clear way to do this with urllib.

Comment: @n0nSmoker Now, in future we have `pathlib` in standard library which is immutable. Although you can easily produce new `Path` changed somehow.

Answer (score 8):

~10 years late to the party here, but today, [pydantic](https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic) provides [several URL types](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#urls) that might be helpful for validating, storing and passing around URLs; with [type hints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) and [`mypy`](https://github.com/python/mypy) becoming more and more prevalent nowadays, some might consider this some kind of standard.

Comment: Pydantic network types: https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/api/networks/#pydantic.networks

Answer (score 5):

What we have as of 2018:

- [purl](https://github.com/codeinthehole/purl),
- [YURL](https://github.com/homm/yurl/),
- [furl](https://github.com/gruns/furl).

Only furl is being maintained today but its major disadvantage is that it's mutable, that doesn't encourage best practices, of course. (There is good modern reference — `pathlib` which consists of immutable classes.)

Overall, having a painless OO way to parse and construct URLs is graeat.

## Update

[yarl](https://pypi.org/project/yarl/) is worth looking at.

Answer (score 2):

[urlpath](https://pypi.org/project/urlpath/) is my go-to for a URL object. It mirrors the `pathlib Path` object.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import urllib3
>>> help(urllib3.util.url)
...
CLASSES
Url(builtins.tuple)
    Url

class Url(Url)
 |  Url(scheme=None, auth=None, host=None, port=None, path=None, query=None, fragment=None)
 |  
 |  Data structure for representing an HTTP URL. Used as a return value for
 |  :func:`parse_url`. Both the scheme and host are normalized as they are
 |  both case-insensitive according to RFC 3986.
 |  
 |  Method resolution order:
 |      Url
 |      Url
 |      builtins.tuple
 |      builtins.object
```